# configuring jshint on VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have code using `spread(...)` and my jshint underlined it saying:

> 'object spread property' is only available in ES9 (use 'esversion: 9'). (W119) jshint(W119)

```
var morning = {
    breakfast: "oatmeal",
    lunch: "peanut and jelly",
    eat() {
        console.log("will eat later");
    }
};
var dinner = "mac and chees";
var backpackingMeals = {

    ...morning,
    dinner
};
console.log(backpackingMeals);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these comments before and after the line:

```
        /*jshint -W119*/
//your line goes here
        /*jshint +W119*/
```